# Yum repository giving 404 on primary_db

Tags: centos, yum

We are trying to install a package from an internal mirror of the EPEL repository. When we do so, we get the following error message:

```
epel/primary_db            FAILED
https://yum.example.com/yum/EPEL/7/x86_64/repodata/cee535f542076e9b28a71100daf379d696383d5628fdd4571f37dae6f918d0cf0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror
https://yum.example.com/yum/EPEL/7/x86_64/repodata/cee535f542076e9b28a71100daf379d696383d5628fdd4571f37dae6f918d0cf0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror


 One of the configured repositories failed (epel),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point, the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:
<snip several options for disabling the repository>

failure: repodata/cee535f542076e9b28a71100daf379d696383d5628fdd4571f37dae6f918d0cf0-primary.sqlite.bz2 from epel: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://yum.example.com/yum/EPEL/7/x86_64/repodata/cee535f542076e9b28a71100daf379d696383d5628fdd4571f37dae6f918d0cf0-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Looking at yum.example.com/yum/EPEL/7/x86_64/repodata/ in a browser, we see entries for 73d6...46bd-primary.sqlite.bz2 and af97...d886-primary.sqlite.bz2; however, there is no entry for cee5...0cf0-primary.sqlite.bz2. How do we fix this issue?

---

The following are the full contents of /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:

```
[epel]
sslverify=0
description=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=https://yum.example.com/yum/EPEL/$releasever/$basearch
gpgcheckk=0
name=epel
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check for me would be diskspace:

```
df -h
```

If you got that right, I would go about re-initializing the local yum cache. Several promising links show up in Google with "reinitialize local yum cache". Check the size of your local cache before and after you do this with:

```
sudo du -sh /var/cache/yum/
```

Good luck.

Comment: I had previously tried `yum clean` to no effect. The solution was to add `yum makecache` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Check
`https://yum.example.com/yum/EPEL/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml`. The links in that file are most likely outdated and need to be updated by the repo admin.